# Adding random numbers in dicom images using Matlab

Tags: matlab, dicom

I am modifying dicom images by replacing the actual pixel values with fixed numbers. Here is one line of my script (below).

```
image_list=dir('*.dcm');

for i=1:40
img=dicomread(image_list(i).name);
imgHdr = dicominfo(image_list(i).name);
%Bone 
img(1:410,1:410) = 3000*uint16(img(1:410,1:410)>1590 & img(1:410,1:410)   <=3000)+uint16(img(1:410,1:410)<=1590 | img(1:410,1:410)>2000).*img(1:410,1:410);

dicomwrite(img, ['N' num2str(i) '.dcm'], imgHdr,'CreateMode','Copy')
end
```

Then, I am trying to add random numbers (between 1 and 100) to these fixed values, i.e. 3000 (as shown in the script) so it will be between 3000 and 3100. How can I do that ?

Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what does not work exactly?

Comment: the line is working fine but I don't know how to add random numbers in my scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add random integers uniformly distributed, you should go for `randi`

so for example this code:

```
img(1:410,1:410)= img(1:410,1:410) +randi([3000 3100],410,410);
```

would add to the existing image pseudorandom uniformly distributed integers from 3000 to 3100.

Comment: I have 8 fixed values in the resultant image. Would be possible to add random numbers for specified fixed values (i.e. only for 3000 value and other than that keep it the same) ?